# Load images in jQuery modal only on modal open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal div which is hidden by default.

The div contains a few images and I want to load the page as quickly as possible.

Is it possible to actually load the images only when the modal is opened and not before?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a model `Dialog` this is easy if you append the `img` element when the dialog is shown for the first time. You can do this via the `open` event of the `Dialog`:

```
var hasOpened = false;

$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   open: function(event, ui) { 
      if (!hasOpened) {
         $('#dialog').append($('<img src="someurl"></img>'));
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you have to load the images into the divider when the user clicks a link model ,

For this you need to write an ajax call to load the images after clicking the link